# Choosing a statistical test for three trials with continuous outcome

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, experiment-design

I have some data that represents three trials where cell populations were divided into two evenly sized groups. One group received no treatment while the other group received treatments (the treatments are using the same methodology although the actual treatment may vary depending on the individual). The outcome data is the number of cells in each population at the end of the period.
What would be the appropriate statistical test to detect a difference in population size between the two groups (treatment vs no treatment) after a fixed amount of time in each trial, t1?

```
| trial | treatment group | no treatment group |
|-------|-----------------|--------------------|
| 1     | x1              | y1                 |
| 2     | x2              | y2                 |
| 3     | x3              | y3                 |
```

To determine whether the presence of treatment had an impact on the population size (x, y) for each group, I would use a Student's t-test, but I am unsure given that the treatment itself can vary from cell to cell.